# Connect to api with (while True:)

Tags: api, web-scraping

I find a lot of tutorials about scrapy data with Api(youtube, BTC, and other). I don't understand why people use constuctions like this without any delay, like below:

```py
while True:
    r = request(url)
```

For me it's look like attacking (overloading) the server. When I **scrape** data from a html web page, I always delay requests to avoid the site to ban me or my IP/fingerprint. Does Api work differently or it's just a bad implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Which python library are you using to scrap the data?

Comment: for html scraping Beautiful soap and Selenium.
But for api just (import requests) simple library. And examples with  (while True) also use requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that tutorials may just want to show a simple solution for the problem, omitting things like API request limits (per time). They don't expect you to make enough requests to be banned. Introducing a delay between requests is good practice, try to discover what is the API limit per time, and distribute your requests accordingly.

Let me know if this helps you!

Comment: No problem @Dmitry_scraping. Happy coding!